# What type of function argument declaration does this C function has?

Tags: c++, c

I'm Working on FFTW (Fastest Fourier Transform in the West) and came over this C function. I did not understand the declaration of this function where parameters are present inside ()(). I never saw a declaration as such. Can anyone brief it out?

```
void X(execute_dft_r2c)(const X(plan) p, R *in, C *out)
    {
      /*
       *Body
       */
    }
```

Comment: C or C++, please choose one. These are two different languages. It is particularly surprising that you chose the specific C++14 version but are talking only about C. Don't tag a version either, if you are not asking about or using specifically that version.

Comment: Are you working with this function in a C or C++ program/ source code?

Comment: Are there any macros defined in that source file (like maybe one named `X`?)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that `X` was a macro that did name mangling or something

Comment: Found the function definition [here](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/d59abdaaeb31af8a7d7f2d2ffa92931efd344e6c/api/execute-dft-r2c.c#L25) and the macro definition [here](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/d59abdaaeb31af8a7d7f2d2ffa92931efd344e6c/kernel/ifftw.h#L62-L78). I love open source!

Comment: It's part of a [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). The function itself isn't meaningful without the `#define X`, which is why placing them in different files wasn't the best idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`X` is a macro that adds a precision-naming prefix depending on compilation parameters.

I believe the point (at least one of them) is to avoid mismatches by causing errors if source files have been compiled with different precision settings.
(C does not have type-safe linkage.)

Look in [fftw3/kernel/ifftw.h](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/d59abdaaeb31af8a7d7f2d2ffa92931efd344e6c/kernel/ifftw.h#L62-L78):

```
/* determine precision and name-mangling scheme */
#define CONCAT(prefix, name) prefix ## name
#if defined(FFTW_SINGLE)
  typedef float R;
# define X(name) CONCAT(fftwf_, name)
#elif defined(FFTW_LDOUBLE)
  typedef long double R;
# define X(name) CONCAT(fftwl_, name)
# define TRIGREAL_IS_LONG_DOUBLE
#elif defined(FFTW_QUAD)
  typedef __float128 R;
# define X(name) CONCAT(fftwq_, name)
# define TRIGREAL_IS_QUAD
#else
  typedef double R;
# define X(name) CONCAT(fftw_, name)
#endif
```

In the first case, your declaration expands to

```
void fftwf_execute_dft_r2c(const fftwf_plan p, R *in, C *out)
```